# 1-hidden layer neural network with rectified linear units

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, classification, mnist

My goal is to implement a 1-hidden layer neural network with rectified linear units `nn.relu()` and 1024 hidden nodes.

```py
# These are all the modules we'll be using later. Make sure you can import them
# before proceeding further.
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import tarfile
from IPython.display import display, Image
from scipy import ndimage
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlretrieve
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
from six.moves import range
import tensorflow as tf

url = 'https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/books1000/'
last_percent_reported = None
data_root = '.' # Change me to store data elsewhere

def download_progress_hook(count, blockSize, totalSize):
  """A hook to report the progress of a download. This is mostly intended for users with
  slow internet connections. Reports every 5% change in download progress.
  """
  global last_percent_reported
  percent = int(count * blockSize * 100 / totalSize)

  if last_percent_reported != percent:
    if percent % 5 == 0:
      sys.stdout.write("%s%%" % percent)
      sys.stdout.flush()
    else:
      sys.stdout.write(".")
      sys.stdout.flush()

    last_percent_reported = percent

def maybe_download(filename, expected_bytes, force=False):
  """Download a file if not present, and make sure it's the right size."""
  dest_filename = os.path.join(data_root, filename)
  if force or not os.path.exists(dest_filename):
    print('Attempting to download:', filename) 
    filename, _ = urlretrieve(url + filename, dest_filename, reporthook=download_progress_hook)
    print('\nDownload Complete!')
  statinfo = os.stat(dest_filename)
  if statinfo.st_size == expected_bytes:
    print('Found and verified', dest_filename)
  else:
    raise Exception(
      'Failed to verify ' + dest_filename + '. Can you get to it with a browser?')
  return dest_filename

# If error in download get it here: http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/notMNIST/
train_filename = maybe_download('notMNIST_large.tar.gz', 247336696)
test_filename = maybe_download('notMNIST_small.tar.gz', 8458043)

num_classes = 10
np.random.seed(133)

def maybe_extract(filename, force=False):
  root = os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])[0]  # remove .tar.gz
  if os.path.isdir(root) and not force:
    # You may override by setting force=True.
    print('%s already present - Skipping extraction of %s.' % (root, filename))
  else:
    print('Extracting data for %s. This may take a while. Please wait.' % root)
    tar = tarfile.open(filename)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    tar.extractall(data_root)
    tar.close()
  data_folders = [
    os.path.join(root, d) for d in sorted(os.listdir(root))
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, d))]
  if len(data_folders) != num_classes:
    raise Exception(
      'Expected %d folders, one per class. Found %d instead.' % (
        num_classes, len(data_folders)))
  print(data_folders)
  return data_folders

train_folders = maybe_extract(train_filename)
test_folders = maybe_extract(test_filename)

pickle_file = 'notMNIST.pickle'

with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as f:
    save = pickle.load(f,encoding='latin1')
    train_dataset = save['train_dataset']
    train_labels = save['train_labels']
    valid_dataset = save['valid_dataset']
    valid_labels = save['valid_labels']
    test_dataset = save['test_dataset']
    test_labels = save['test_labels']
    del save  # hint to help gc free up memory
    print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
    print('Validation set', valid_dataset.shape, valid_labels.shape)
    print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)

image_size = 28
num_labels = 10

def reformat(dataset, labels):
  dataset = dataset.reshape((-1, image_size * image_size)).astype(np.float32)
  # Map 0 to [1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ...], 1 to [0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ...]
  labels = (np.arange(num_labels) == labels[:,None]).astype(np.float32)
  return dataset, labels
train_dataset, train_labels = reformat(train_dataset, train_labels)
valid_dataset, valid_labels = reformat(valid_dataset, valid_labels)
test_dataset, test_labels = reformat(test_dataset, test_labels)
print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
print('Validation set', valid_dataset.shape, valid_labels.shape)
print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)

batch_size = 128
hidden_nodes = 1024

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

    x_train = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size * image_size)) 
    y_ =  tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels)) 
    x_valid = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
    x_test = tf.constant(test_dataset)

    hidden_layer = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x_train,hidden_nodes)

    logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(hidden_layer, num_labels, activation_fn=None)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=y_ ) )

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

    train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    valid_relu = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x_valid,hidden_nodes)
    valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(valid_relu,num_labels))

    test_relu = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x_test,hidden_nodes, activation_fn=None)
    test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(test_relu,num_labels, activation_fn=None))

steps = 3001

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    for step in range(steps):
        # Selecting some portion within training data 
        # Note: Better to randomize dataset for Minibatch SGD
        offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
        # Generate the Minibatch
        batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        # Feed the batch size to dict
        feed_dict = {x_train: batch_data, y_:batch_labels}
        _, l, prediction = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        if(step % 500 == 0):
            print("Minibatch Loss at step %d: %f"% (step, l))
            print("Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(prediction,batch_labels))
            print("Validation accuracy :%.1f%% "% accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(),valid_labels))



    print('Test accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))
```

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/santiaago/udacity.ud730.deeplearning/blob/master/assignments/2_fullyconnected.ipynb) and it got better accuracy than my code.

I wanted to achieve similar result by using `tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected` as hidden layer did I do it correctly?

**EDIT:**

Changed input to hidden_layer in logits

Reworked valid_relu, valid_prediction, test_relu, test_prediction

**Result:**

```py
Minibatch Loss at step 0: 2.389448
Minibatch accuracy: 5.5%
Validation accuracy :8.2% 
Minibatch Loss at step 500: 0.342108
Minibatch accuracy: 92.2%
Validation accuracy :8.2% 
Minibatch Loss at step 1000: 0.543803
Minibatch accuracy: 84.4%
Validation accuracy :8.2% 
Minibatch Loss at step 1500: 0.299978
Minibatch accuracy: 93.8%
Validation accuracy :8.2% 
Minibatch Loss at step 2000: 0.294090
Minibatch accuracy: 93.8%
Validation accuracy :8.2% 
Minibatch Loss at step 2500: 0.333070
Minibatch accuracy: 90.6%
Validation accuracy :8.2% 
Minibatch Loss at step 3000: 0.365324
Minibatch accuracy: 89.1%
Validation accuracy :8.2% 
Test accuracy: 6.8%
```

Comment: Just use Estimator instead ...

Answer (score 1):

You started out right. Here're few additions:

- Since you're getting rid of manual FC layers in faviour of `tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected`, drop `w` and `b` as well. This will save you time picking the right initialization for those weights:

```py
hidden_layer = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x_train, hidden_nodes)
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(hidden_layer, num_labels, 
                                           activation_fn=None)
```

- It's a bad to practice to put your dataset right into the graph as constants and also duplicate inference nodes, even in a tutorial. Instead, simply push `valid_dataset` and `test_dataset` as `feed_dict` and evaluate `train_prediction`.

```py
# BAD idea: this potentially large value is stored in the graph, can lead to OOM
x_valid = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
x_test = tf.constant(test_dataset)
...
# BAD idea: model duplication
valid_relu = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x_valid, hidden_nodes)
valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(valid_relu, w) + b)
test_relu = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x_test, hidden_nodes)
test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(test_relu, w) + b)
```

- Also note that `tensorflow.contrib` is an experimental package. Particularly, `fully_connected` layer has been "graduated" to [`tf.layers.dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense). It's doing the same job, but its API is guaranteed to be stable, while `fully_connected` can be deprecated in the next releases.

Comment: I got new ValueError: Input 0 of layer fully_connected_1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=0. Full shape received: []

Comment: Corrected: the input should be the hidden layer output. If any new errors come up, update the question with the **reproducible example**